# Can "considered" be used as an adjective?

Tags: grammar

Whilst translating a piece of English copy to Dutch, I came accross a sentence that used the word 'considered' as an adjective:
"It is an elegant and considered shirt." I honestly don't know what to make of that. Any suggestions?

Comment: *Considered* can definitely be used as an adjective. [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considered): "*adjective:* resulting from careful thought". Whether it should be applied to shirts is a different question.

Comment: Maybe' well-chosen' would be more idiomatic. I'm not really sure what a 'considered shirt' could be.

Comment: In my considered opinion, this may not mean what you mean for it to mean. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a more traditional, English way to say "well considered". I think it means 'tasteful' in this context.

Comment: It doesn't mean "tasteful", it means the wearer gave the choice of shirt a lot of attention to ensure they picked just the correct one for the occasion, leading to giving just the right sartorial impression.

Comment: . . . as opposed to dressing with *studied indifference.*